# Any static code analysis tools for C# 4.0 yet?

Tags: c#-4.0, code-analysis

Pretty straightforward question here: I like tools such as [FxCop](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/) when it comes to scanning assemblies to get better insight into my code, and would like to start doing it on C# 4.0 assemblies. Any out there yet, or should I sit tight for a few more months while it's released and tools are updated?

Answer (score 3):

The VS2010 beta includes a newer version of Code Analysis, which runs FxCop during the build process and displays the output as warnings.  See the Code Analysis tab of project properties.

However, it's only available in the Premium and Ultimate editions.  (See [comparison](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010/default.mspx?CR_CC=100253223&WT.mc_id=SEARCH&WT.srch=1&CR_SCC=100253223))

I really wish that Microsoft would include it in the Express Editions and enable it by default for all projects; that might substantially improve beginner code.

Comment: Interesting! Though I downloaded VS2010 Pro last week (10.0.21006.1 B2Rel) and don't see it on a class-output project's properties. Maybe because I updated the project from a 2008 project? I'll dig into it.

Comment: I believe it's only available in Premium and Ultimate.

Answer (score 3):

What about [`Microsoft StyleCop for Visual Studio 2010`](http://blogs.msdn.com/sourceanalysis/archive/2010/01/04/stylecop-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

The tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) supports C#4, and even now C#5. It integrates inside Visual Studio 2012, 2010 and 2008. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

The tool propose many facilities for your need of **scanning assemblies to get better insight into my code**, like [Dependency Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx), [Dependency Matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx), [Code Metrics](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx), [Code Diff capabilities](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Diff.aspx)...

If you like FxCop, then you'll find useful the NDepend possibility to write [Code Query and Code Rule over LINQ Queries (namely CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). More than [200 CQLinq code queries and rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed by default.

It is easy to write your own ones or customize existing ones. CQLinq queries are compiled and executed instantly and their results are presented in a *browsable-friendly* way, see the screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [SD C# Clone Doctor](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone/CSharpCloneDR.html) statically analyzes C# (yes, even version 4.0) source code for duplication.

The CloneDR can be applied to large scale software systems, and typically finds 10-20% duplicated code.

There is a sample clone report at the link.